# Rails association that specifies foreign key and where options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to associate two tables where a specific condition is true.

It's a 'user has books in a collection' sort of schema.  That collection can be either a **library** or a **wishlist**.

There's a users table (pretty standard), a books table(details irrelevant), and a joins table called collection_books, which looks like this:

id | user_id | book_id | collection_type

Using [Rails Docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-where) as a reference, my code looks like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :library_collection_books,
        foreign_key: :user_id,
        class_name: :CollectionBook,
        -> { where collection_type: 'library'}
end
```

vs the Rails Docs sample code:

```
class Parts < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assemblies,
    -> { where "factory = 'Seattle'" }
end
```

This is the error I get in rails console:

```
user.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
```

I'm guessing it's not specific to the `has_and_belongs_to` association type, so the problem must be the syntax of how I'm specifying foreign key and class name.

For the record, I can just do

```
has_many :collection_books,
   -> { where collection_type: 'library' }
```

and it does work.  But I'm going to need this association for either library or wishlist books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda `-> { ... }` has to be the first argument *(or second depending on how you count it)*

```
has_many :library_collection_books,
    -> { where collection_type: 'library'},
    foreign_key: :user_id,
    class_name: 'CollectionBook'
```